# 403 Forbidden when using a dir wildcard

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, wildcard, http-status-code-403, dynamic

I am using a wild card so that I do not have to create a dir listing for each folder I create I can access `folder.dev/index.html` correctly but when I try to access `folder.dev` I am getting a  `403`based on the folder I am trying to access `/Users/Jess/Sites/dev/test/` and the error `Directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Why?

```
<Directory "/Users/Jess/Sites/dev/*">
Options All
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `/*` at the end of the Directory line. The wildcard is implied and unnecessary.

```
<Directory "/Users/Jess/Sites/dev">
```

If that doesn't work, instead of `Options All` try `Options Indexes`

Comment: nope :( still 403

Answer (score 0):

You're probably setting Options differently in Location/LocationMatch which overrides this configuration.